# Load part of an external page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to load an part of an external page with javascript. The part is definied with a class, which exists muliple time on the page.

My script doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#highprice').load('https:/www.mysite.com .price');
```

I think it isn't working, because the the class .`price` is not unique. I want to show all the parts of the page which are wrapped by the `.price`-Class

Comment: Are you sure the the element with the `price` class is actually in the HTML source?  If the page is dynamically created and augmented with JavaScript at run-time, I don't think it will be considered because that element doesn't exist until a browser would run the JS on the page.

Comment: There's no way you can achieve what you want with `.load()`. You can't just randomly add a class selector next to the URL and expect it to extract an element from the page at that URL.

Comment: I've figured it out ;-) I just wrote something like that $('#highprice').load('https:/www.mysite.com .price .product-list > li:first-of-type span');